# выражения только для положительных чисел

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

как совсем не давать вводить ненужные значения в поле инпут
таким образом ничего не происходит . То бишь в поле сразу был запрещен ввод кроме цифр

js

```
var input = document.getElementById('place'),
       reg = "/^[\d]+$/g";
    input.value = input.value.replace(reg, '');
```

Comment: А в какой момент времени, по-вашему, бежит приведённый вами код?

Comment: [type="number"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html)

Comment: в данном случае он находится в функции которая обрабатывает событие инпута, и код должен выполнятся как только что-то вводится в поле ввода

Comment: @dirk, вы неверно пытаетесь использовать регулярное выражение, уберите вокруг него кавычки и все должно заработать

Comment: убрал, но символы пропускает как и раньше(

Comment: разве что четырёхзначные цифры не пускает

Comment: создайте пример добавив snippet тут или на jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dirkdirk/rct7xmLc/2/

Comment: @dirk Кроме вышесказанного (что выражение не должно быть в кавычках) оно у вас написано с точностью до наоборот и произведет полное удаление содержимого input только в том случае если там будут только цифры. Что бы удалять НЕ цифры надо написать `/[^\d]/g` и все, более ничего не добавлять, никаких начал и концов строки

Comment: благодарствую! теперь работает

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
var input = document.getElementById('place'),
input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

Т.е. удаляем все "НЕ цифры"

Comment: в принципе и `[`,`]` не нужны

Comment: а как сделать что бы и "-" не пропускало

Comment: @dirk А оно его разве пропускает ?

Comment: @Grundy `[]` убирать нельзя, без них `^` будет считаться началом строки, а не отрицанием `\d`

Comment: там `value="1"` и получается после той "1" не пропускает, но если выставить курсор перед единицей - то пропускает

Comment: @Mike, ага, надо просто другой класс использовать :)

Comment: @dirk Я проверял так: `"-123-456sgr".replace(/[^\d]/g,'')` результат `123456`

Comment: @dirk, а какой результат вы ожидали? а, это оказывается Mike отвечал :)

Comment: понял, нужно было не в конец метода проверку вставлять, теперь ок

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант

```
input.value = input.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

> [\D](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes) - Сопоставляется с любым символом, который не является цифрой в базовом латинском алфавите. Эквивалентен набору символов [^0-9].

```js
$('#inp').on('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inp" type="text" />
```